# How to pass a value from ng-click to controller function? and How to use that assigned value outside the function

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <a href="#" ng-click="g(101)">Link</a><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.g=function(e){

    $scope.firstName = e;}
    $scope.lastName = $scope.firstName;
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

From the above code when the "link" is clicked I want to display 101 101. But the $scope.lastname is showing the value 101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a syntax error. update your function to:

```
$scope.g=function(e){

    $scope.firstName = e;
    $scope.lastName = $scope.firstName;
}
```

That being said If you think the value will automatically change because you set `$scope.lastName = $scope.firstName;` the first time?

That only works in case of Objects. because they're passed by reference, hence reflect change. but in case on a string (as for in this case), `$scope.lastName` will not change automatically if  `$scope.firstName` is changed

Comment: If I want to pass the value of the $scope.firstname as to another variable in controller outside of function what should be done.